# How to make eclipse show file at line last viewed upon program start or upon file open/reopen

Tags: java, eclipse, class, xhtml, preferences

When I open a Java file (or class file with source code) in Eclipse, the editor shows the file at the line that I last viewed it, prior to when I last closed the file, or deactivated the task, or closed Eclipse.

That's ok.

How do I get this to work for xhtml files?

If I go window > preferences > General > Editors, I can select the box "Restore editor state on startup".

But, if I am not mistaken, that doesn't help for xhtml files.

Comment: Anybody have something to say about this, yay or nay?